# How to uninstall NetBeans 7.1.2 after system restore in Windows XP ?

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall, system-restore, netbeans

I did a system restore on my laptop running on Windows XP. After the system restore procedure, NetBeans 7.1.2 will not execute anymore. I uninstalled NetBeans, but the uninstall procedure could not remove NetBeans anymore. How can I uninstall NetBeans?

Comment: Do you get any specific error messages when you try to execute or remove it? Please [edit] your question and add these, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear because you haven't stated how the uninstaller failed. With the information you have provided I think the most universal solution is to reinstall the same version of Netbeans into the same directory, with identical installation choices. That should fix problems with your current install and leave you with working Netbeans (if you want to continue using it) and working uninstaller (if you want to get rid of it).

Answer (score 0):

You just have to delete the folder ".nbi" and try to uninstall or install it again.
This folder could be encountered in "C:\Users\{USER}"

Answer (score -1):

just go to the program files that is present in c partition and search for the file that includes netbeans and delete it, by this way you will need to re-install netbeans if you needed it again

Comment: -1. How do you know it's installed in `C:\Program Files` ? Deleting from there won't take care of registry entries. This really is a bad answer.